# Read /dev/urandom into c string buffer

Tags: c, string

I am trying to read a fixed length of contents from `/dev/urandom` into a string buffer in C. However, the number of bytes read are different every time I call the program. Below is my code snippet

```
char * buff = malloc(sizeof(char)*2048);
int fd = open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY);
read(fd, buff, 2048);
printf("%lu \n", strlen(buff)); // length varies but usually not 2048
printf("%s \n",  buff);
```

Does this behavior happen because string is `\0` terminated in C, so suppose there is `\0` in the first 2048 characters, the contents after the first `\0` will be truncated?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can look at the return value of `read(fd, ...)` to know how many bytes were actually read instead of using `strlen`. Like you guessed, there is `\0` somewhere which is causing the string to be truncated. Even worse, there could be no `\0` in the entire 2048 characters read and calling `strlen` on this would lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: What purpose does reading binary data into a C string have? Do you *need* the data as a string? (In which case you should filter or postprocess the stream from urandom.) Or don't you know any other way to store binary data?

Comment: Note that random data includes null bytes, and those terminate the string that's presented by `read()`.  Note too that `read()` does not null-terminate the data; what it returns is a byte array, not a string.  You're seeing manifestations of these properties.  In particular, if by chance none of the 2048 bytes is a null byte, your code will go tramping out of bounds looking for a null byte.  You'd need to capture the length read and print that many bytes: `int nbytes = read(fd, buff, 2048); printf("%.*s\n", nbytes, buff);` — but that will still stop at a null byte.

Comment: Also, reading 2048 bytes from a random device is a *huge* amount. The [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/4/urandom) suggests no more than 32 bytes at a go. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Check that the `read()` actually succeeded! This is important because there is no guarantee that `/dev/urandom` will actually exist. For examples, in chroot environments without a `/dev` directory.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to load it into a string, I think that here you want to read the random int produced by `/dev/urandom`, so something like this should work :

```
  int randomvalue;
  FILE *fpointer;
  fpointer = fopen("/dev/urandom", "rb");
  fread(&randomvalue,sizeof(int),1,fpointer);  
  fclose(fpointer);
```

Comment: Don't forget to check that `fpointer` is not `NULL`, and that `fread()` returns `1`.